# How to get clone element and add div tag before appending

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get the clone elements from iframe html using queryselectorall and also append to another element. I want to add surounding div tag for each query selector element before appending.

Now i have output like this

```
    <div class="optedit_summary" id="opteditsum">
    <span id="pc1430568488933" class="optbold">nde</span>
    <span id="pc1430568582173" class="optdel">fas</span>
    <span id="pc1430914284123" class="optdel">non</span>
    </div>
```

Need as like below

```
    <div class="optedit_summary" id="opteditsum">
    <div><span id="pc1430568488933" class="optbold">nde</span></div>
    <div><span id="pc1430568582173" class="optdel">fas</span></div>
    <div><span id="pc1430914284123" class="optdel">non</span></div>
    </div>
```

This is my code for cloning and append element

```
    var elements = document.getElementById('main_iframe').contentDocument.querySelectorAll(".optdel, .optbold");
    var editsummary = document.getElementById("opteditsum");

    for (var i = 0, im = elements.length; im > i; i++) {
        editsummary.appendChild(elements[i].cloneNode(true));
    }
```

Comment: Your ouput and expected as same what the diffrences here?

Comment: div tag added on each span

Answer (score 1):

Since your solution does not use jQuery, you can create a div element then append the clone to that element like

```
var elements = document.getElementById('main_iframe').contentDocument.querySelectorAll(".optdel, .optbold");
var editsummary = document.getElementById("opteditsum");

var div;
for (var i = 0, im = elements.length; im > i; i++) {
    div = document.createElement('div');
    div.appendChild(elements[i].cloneNode(true))
    editsummary.appendChild(div);
}
```

---

Using jQuery the entire code can be as simple as

```
var $els = $('#main_iframe').contents().find('.optdel, .optbold');
$els.clone().wrap('<div />').parent().appendTo('#opteditsum');
```

Comment: @kaliaperumal.p what do you mean by empty tag... where do you want to create it

Comment: No, Before append the clone element, i want to make empty tag(#opteditsum) for each click.

Comment: Thanks i got@Arun
$('#opteditsum').empty();
var $els = $('#main_iframe').contents().find('.optdel, .optbold');
$els.clone().wrap('<div />').parent().appendTo('#opteditsum');